# Display when user was last active

Tags: php, date, time

Using PHP, how can I display how long ago a user was active using the information below.

Database table `users_activity`

```
| Username  |  Time               |
----------------------------------
| User1     |2013-09-19 12:29:25  |
| User2     |2013-04-19 11:24:54  |
__________________________________
```

How I would like it to be displayed on the website page:

`Last Active: 430 days 12 hours 58 minutes 45 seconds ago`

Comment: Since those dates are in the future you'll get some really weird results. Also, what do you have so far? (show us your code)

Comment: lol yes, weird results. But I was showing the datetime format I was using in my tables. Right now I have it just displaying the result above for each user. As in: `echo $result['Time'];` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mktime` to format and then `floor` to compare.

This link should help: [PHP Date Difference](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-date-difference.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! That should work :) If so, I'll mark your answer.